# get contents and permalink base on the specified page title on the query

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

below is a query where it supposed to get a contents from a page by a specified page title

```
<?php
    $page = get_page_by_title( 'About Us' );
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 

    the_content_rss('', TRUE, '', 100);
?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Read the whole post" class="rm">Read More</a>
```

and yes its successfully display a content and trim the content by 100, but the problem is the content and permalink is not the content and the permalink of the specified page that I pulled from the query, i mean, the content and permalink is different from the page Im pulling up. Any ideas whats going on? Im trying to play around with the code but seems nothing works at all and also im currently looking on the web for the possible solution but unfortunately, I find nothing.

PS: I just want to display the content and get the permalink of the specified page that im pulling up through the query above.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following code?

```
<?php
    $page = get_page_by_title( 'About Us' );
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
    echo substr($content,0,30);  
?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $page->ID ) ); ?>">title="Read the whole post" class="rm">Read More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out, thanks to everybody here..

my updated code is

```
<?php
    $page = get_page_by_title( 'About Us' );
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 

     echo wp_trim_words( $content, 100, '');
?>

<a href="<?php  echo get_permalink( $page->ID ); ?>" title="Read the whole post" class="rm">Read More</a>
```